# Android AudioTrack delay when resuming

Tags: java, android

I have an application that needs to pause and resume an `AudioTrack` quite frequently and this issue has been tested and seen on multiple devices. When the AudioTrack is played and paused, don't do anything in a few seconds, then resume the audio, then there's a delay, about 0.3 secs. If you then pause and resume it immediately, there will be no delay.

Here's the logcat when there is no delay: (from cm-11-20140521-NIGHTLY-i9500)

```
D/AudioFlinger( 2578): start(4098), calling pid 13180 session 3204
D/AudioFlinger( 2578): PAUSED => RESUMING (4098) on thread 0xb730ae40
```

Here's the logcat when there is delay:

```
D/AudioFlinger( 2578): start(4098), calling pid 13180 session 3204
D/AudioFlinger( 2578): PAUSED => RESUMING (4098) on thread 0xb730ae40
V/audio_hw_primary( 2578): start_output_stream: starting stream
V/audio_hw_primary( 2578): start_output_stream: stream out device: 2, actual: 2
```

And I guess it's the `start_output_stream` thing or GC that causes the delay. Does anyone know how to fix this?

P.S. Here's the background code:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionevent) {
    switch (motionevent.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            pressed = true;
            (new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /* Generate savedTrack */
                    if (pressed) savedTrack.play();
                }
            })).start();
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            pressed = false;
            if (savedTrack != null) savedTrack.pause();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it turns out that if there is no `STREAM_MUSIC` audio playing for a while, the output device/stream will shut itself down and causes a delay when resuming the audio. So the solution is simple: play a muted looped track in the background when the app is foreground.

Another thing I noticed is that if your `AudioTrack` is less than 16 samples, it won't loop. Hope this help.